# how to give echo function in $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', '');

Tags: php, phpexcel

how to give echo function in

```
      $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', 'Actual Spending FY 2012-2013');
```

in the above code instead of 2012-2013 i have to use `<?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')).'-'.date('Y'); ?>`, how to assign it. can someone help me thanks.

Comment: Could you please explain just a little better what is your doubt? :)

Comment: What did you just say?

Comment: i mean that in Actual Spending FY 2012-2013 am using the year statically, i need to change it dynamically by using <?php echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')).'-'.date('Y'); ?>,   how i have to specify this code instead of 2012-2013 in the place of string

Comment: You are using PHPExcel and do not know about string [basic string manipulation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)?

Comment: in this particular place how to use is not known  $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', 'Actual Spending FY echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')).'-'.date('Y'); '); is this the correct format or not

Comment: @user3165411, no that's incorrect (see also my answer). I suggest you follow a good PHP tutorial. This is all basic stuff. Good luck in your learnings!

Comment: is that no need to use echo here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, just concat it in:

```
$s = 'Actual Spending FY '.date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')).'-'.date('Y');
$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B3', $s);
```

Comment: $s = 'Actual Spending FY '.echo date('Y', strtotime('-1 year')).'-'.date('Y'); is this correct or not?

Comment: No, echo is not needed, you pass variable value to a function parameter.